# How to truncate extension off in-line variable %name% in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2

I have seen similar questions but no clear answer and I am afraid that this can't be done in ModelBuilder alone.

Is there a way to truncate the extension off the %name% variable? I am working with .tif and .asc files that I use to resample and do zonal statistics but since they have file extensions the tools throw an error when using %name% and I am forced to use %n% and then rename the files using R. I have tried "%name%"[x:y] as suggested in another question but doesn't work.

Any suggestions? This is ArcMap 10.2 but had the same problem in 10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the [Parse Path (ModelBuilder)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000008000000) tool which may have been new at ArcGIS 10.1:

> The **Parse Path** tool parses the input into its file, path, name, or
>   extension. The output can be used as in-line variables in the output
>   name of other tools.

Comment: thanks so much for this! I should have asked earlier and saved a ton of time coding this in R!

Comment: ok I shouldn't have been so exited so quickly. I am having a problem now that the parsing happens before the iteration moves to the next raster. So result2 has the raster1 name.

Comment: If you think this is part of the same initial Question would you be able to edit that to include more details and a diagram of your model, please?  If you think it has moved to a new issue then perhaps research/ask it separately.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `"%Name%".replace(".tif","")` in Calculate Value in ModelBuilder.

Comment: I have same problem. I've alot of tiff files and I want to calculate zonal statistics on polygons in my Shapefile. I am using Arcmap 10.1 how can I use your suggestion please?